# What is the speed of the information transmission between water molecules?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, molecules, molecular-dynamics

What I would like to know is if for example I move a molecule in water how fast this information will reach the neighboring molecules

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: For example $c$ :-)

Comment: @GiorgioP So the answer is the speed of light

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is a comment on your use of "for example," If it is an example, please, try to explain the general question. If it is not an example, please state it clearly.  In passing, it is also a very short answer. A longer could come if you rewrite your question, adding clarity and some context.

Comment: My question is the title "What is the speed of the information transmission between water molecules?" I just tried to give an example to make it more clear but it seems that I didn't succeeded

Comment: I think moving a water molecule, say in liquid water, is like causing a vibration, therefore, I suggest that the information travels with the speed of sound in water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Water molecules in liquid form "communicate" between their nearest neighbors via electrostatic forces, which propagate at the speed of light. But because each water molecule is electrically neutral overall, a particular water molecule 5 molecules away from another water molecule can't "talk" directly to it at c. In this case the one molecule has to bounce off another, which bounces off another, and so on which means the maximum speed with which one molecule can make its presence felt by another *in the bulk* will be set by the speed with which the molecules are bouncing off each other and how much time elapses between bounces.

You can then relate those *molecular speeds* and *mean free path lengths* to the actual *speed of sound* through a large sample of water. So an engineer will answer your question by citing the speed of sound in water, whereas a physicist will instead *question that answer* by citing the molecular speed and mean free path length!

In short, engineers answer questions while physicists question answers. This has been a public service.

Comment: Thank you very much